# Design of c++ class: common use of class members in other class members; Small interface vs small classes

Tags: c++, oop, class-design

Say I have a class A with some member attributes. A also has a vector with objects of class B (`std::vector<B>`). Those B objects need some (let's say 5) of the attributes of A. I see two ways of handling this:

1) Let B have references to those attributes, and assign them in B's constructor.

2) Let B only have a reference to the A object, and get the attributes via public `getAttributeXYZ()` functions.

I can see that solution 1) technically knows less about A, therefore it's better because it couldn't for example call some wrong A function. But I feel like 2) is much cleaner, since the constructor is way smaller and the B class has much fewer (reference-) attributes itself. Is there a general better way or does it depend on the details?

Context: In my program, those members of A are classes for texture management, text drawing etc that can be shared by all of the B objects.

Comment: I don't follow the logic that #1 knows any less about A. If it references the attributes directly, it's still just as dependent upon A. In fact, it is more so, because it relies upon *private* implementation details of A, whereas if you just stored a reference to A and called public accessor functions, there would be less dependency between A and B. I would also argue that trying to minimize dependencies between two things that *are logically dependent* is an exercise in silliness. Use the design that is clearest, even if it is not the most theoretically pure.

Comment: "Is there a general better way or does it depend on the details?": how could we know without knowing the details? :) That's why a good question should be formated as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a general question

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can have your cake and eat it too, by giving the `B`s access to only the relevant subset of `A`. There are multiple ways you could go about this.

One, gather the attributes in a dedicated class:

```
struct A
{
  struct SharedData
  {
    int data;
    // ...
  };

  A();

private:
  SharedData sharedData;
  std::vector<B> bs;
  // other data here
};

struct B
{
  B(A::SharedData *data) : data{data} {}

private:
  A::SharedData *data;
};

A::A() : bs{B{&sharedData}} {}
```

Two, give `A` a dedicated interface to access these attributes:

```
struct SharedDataInterface
{
  virtual int getData() const = 0;
};

struct A : SharedDataInterface
{
  int getData() override { return sharedData; }

  A();

private:
  std::vector<B> bs;
  int sharedData;
  // other data here
};

struct B
{
  B(SharedDataInterface *data) : data{data} {}

private:
  SharedDataInterface *data;
};

A::A() : bs{B{this}} {}
```

I'm sure other variations on this topic are also possible.